# Pass the number of columns in parameter

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report that contains two detail bands. The first one is the larger version of the second. I use a value to display one and hide the other (when it's 1, then the big one is shown, and the little one is hidden).

Here the objective is to save some space when the user wants to display the little version.
Here, an example for two records

```
DisplayParameter = 1 ; (Number of columns = 1)

===========================================================================

                                  Big version 1

===========================================================================
===========================================================================

                                  Big version 2

===========================================================================
```

And now the version with the little one

```
DisplayParameter = 0 ; (Number of columns = 2)

============================    ============================
       Little version 1                Little version 2
============================    ============================
```

It would be perfect if I could pass the number of columns by parameter but I guess it is not possible.
Is there a solution for my problem?

Comment: 1) You can use JasperReports API (or wrappers, such as DynamicReports) for building report dynamically; 2) Using several templates with subreport(s) to avoid duplicating of code; 3) Set columns number via JasperReports API

Comment: It is maybe naive, but how to access JasperReports API through Jaspersoft Studio ? I'm doing my internship, I have only one month and half with Jaspersoft studio, i'm not used to all the terms due to my self-study.